# AWS ALB target group path based routing not working when I change the path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

**EDIT**

I have discovered that adding a route to the node app under `/cms` seems to resolve the issue, however, how can I point to `/` as the default. This seems like annoying behaviour

**END EDIT**

I have an ECS Cluster with one task running, this is picked up by a target group and on the ALB I was routing to this target group on `/` like below:

[image]

When I then grab the DNS from the ALB and hit the url it works fine, I get:

`{"name":"DEMO"}`

I want this service to be routed too only when the user hits `/cms`, so I changed this in the listeners like so:

[image]

However once updated and I hit the url + `/cms` I get:

`Cannot GET /cms`

And I cannot work out why. This is a super basic node express app with the index like below:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 80

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let data = {
        name: "DEMO"
    }
    res.json(data);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Request is:

```
http://yourdomen/[path]/[subpath]
```

where:
`[path]` - It wether `/cms` or `/`

There is Load Balancer forwarding behaviour:

- If Load Balancer get `http://yourdomen/`, it pass `http://yourdomen/` to Express (**not** `/`)
- If Load Balancer get `http://yourdomen/cms`, it also pass "http://yourdomen/cms" to Express without any changing (**not** `/cms`)
- If Load Balancer get `http://yourdomen/cms/[subpath]`, it pass `http://yourdomen/cms/[subpath]` (**not** `/cms/[subpath]`)

Load Balancer can't pass only `subpath` part to Express in **"Forward to"** action. If you want to Load Balancer change your Request before pass it to Express, you should use **"Redirect to"** action

**NOTE** you can use ECS cluster private DNS as host in a redirecting rule, then you won't need a target group

**Redirect** example:

Load Balancer gets `http://yourdomen/cms/[subpath]` and changes the request's route to `http://dummycmsdomen/[subpath]` and redirect this updated route to Express. In this case Express will get `http://yourdomen/[path]` pattern, and works correctly within your scenario

**EDITION PART ANSWER:**

- If you send `http://yourdomen/` then Express should works with `/` path
- If you send `http://yourdomen/cms` then Express should works with `/cms` path

So before you edited code Express app it were waiting for `/` path, but it get `/cms` and should return GET-error.
And after you have added an according directive to process `/cms` path App became to works